# Remove a piece of url and insert another piece in a new position

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've this urls that I'm trying to change in::

```
www.example.it/ mio-pezzo- product-1-url.html --> www.example.com/product-1- my-piece- url.html
www.example.com/product-1- my-piece- url.html --> www.example.it/ mio-pezzo- product-1-url.html
```

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.it$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)my-piece-(.*)$ /$1mio-pezzo-$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)mio-pezzo-(.*)$ /$1my-piece-$2 [L,R=301]
```

but this is result...

```
www.example.it/ mio-pezzo- product-1-url.html --> www.example.com/ my-piece- product-1-url.html
www.example.com/product-1- my-piece- url.html --> www.example.it/product-1- mio-pezzo- url.html
```

How can I do to move it after or before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move `$1` after `mio-pezzo-` on the first RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.it$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)my-piece-(.*)$ /mio-pezzo-$1$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)mio-pezzo-(.*)$ /$1my-piece-$2 [L,R=301]
```